# TypeError: 'QgsGraph' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, algorithm, a-star

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kasun/.qgis2/python/plugins/floogin/floogin.py", line 246, in findRoutes
    path=self.astar.astarSearch(graph, start, end)
  File "/home/kasun/.qgis2/python/plugins/floogin/astar.py", line 110, in astarSearch
    for tile in graph[current]:
TypeError: 'QgsGraph' object does not support indexing
```

Above Error occured when I run the following code. I'm new to qgis and I don't know why the error occurs.I wanted to find path between two selected points.I would really appreciate if you could please help me out to find solution to the problem.
Thank You.

```
def astarSearch(self, graph, current, end):
    openSet = set()
    openHeap = []
    closedSet = set()

    def retracePath(c):
        path = [c]
        while c.parent is not None:
                c = c.parent
                path.append(c)
        path.reverse()
        return path

    openSet.add(current)
    openHeap.append((0,current))
    while openSet:
        current = heapq.heappop(openHeap)[1]
        if current == end:
                return retracePath(current)
        openSet.remove(current)
        closedSet.add(current)
        for tile in graph[current]:
                if tile not in closedSet:
                    tile.H = (abs(end.x-tile.x)+abs(end.y-tile.y))*10 
                    if tile not in openSet:
                            openSet.add(tile)
                            heapq.heappush(openHeap, (tile.H,tile))
                    tile.parent = current
    return []


def findRoutes(self):
vl=self.canvas.currentLayer()
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector( vl, -1, '', '', '', 3 )
properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
director.addProperter( properter )
crs = self.canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
builder = QgsGraphBuilder( crs )

global x1
global y1
global x2
global y2
pStart = QgsPoint( x1, y1 )
pStop = QgsPoint( x2, y2 )

tiedPoints = director.makeGraph( builder, [ pStart, pStop ] )
graph = builder.graph()
tStart = tiedPoints[ 0 ]
tStop = tiedPoints[ 1 ]
idStart = graph.findVertex( tStart )
idStop = graph.findVertex( tStop )

start, end = idStart, idStop
path=self.astarSearch(graph, start, end)
if path is None:
        print "No path found"
else:
    print "Path found:", path
```